# How to add a function to discord.py event loop?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am using Python with `discord.py`. Documentation **[here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)**

I've got a bot that is running on a Discord server that links the server with a subreddit. Users have various commands that do things like getting the top submissions, getting the latest submissions, and so on.

I want to add some features to the bot, with one of them being a keyword notifier. The bot should search the subreddit for keywords in the title, and then notify users if they are on the list for that keyword. I know how to do this, I've done it plenty of times, but I don't know how to do it with a Discord bot. I have no experience with asynchio or any kind of asynchronous programming.

The way I've tried to do it works, but it is very janky and definitely not good. At the top of the `on message()` function, I just add a call to the `search_submissions()` function, so that whenever someone puts sends a new message on the server, the bot will scan the Reddit submissions. The server is busy enough that this would work relatively okay, but I really want to do it the "proper" way.

I don't know how to call the `search_submissions()` function without putting it inside of `on_message()`.

---

Edit for extra code:

```
import discord

TOKEN = "redacted"
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def reddit_search():
    print("Searching")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("reddit!hot"):
        # Get hot
    # Do other things.

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Connected to Discord as {}.".format(client.user.name))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: To clarify: Do you want `search_submissions()` to run continuously or only when a user sends a message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a function to the bot event loop with `Client.loop.create_task(search_submissions())` like this:

```
async def search_submissions():
    pass

client = discord.Client()

client.loop.create_task(search_submissions())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

**Update:**

If you want your function to continue working you can put it in a while loop with some sleeping in between:

```
async def search_submissions():
    while(true):
        # do your stuff
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is `bot`? I don't have that in my code. I edited the code I have in to my original question, but removed all of the stuff inside each function to save space. Everything is there, it's just missing print and if statements.

Comment: @JohnYuki Sorry, I fixed my answer, I am just used to using the `commands` module.

Comment: No problem. So I added the `create_task` line, but it doesn't go over it. It goes through the function once when I start the bot but that's it.

Comment: @JohnYuki Updated my answer.

Comment: How does `search_submissions()` communicate its results with the rest of the bot?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers here don't take into account discord.py's helpful `tasks.loop` decorator.

To make an event occur every 5 seconds, you would use

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def foo(self):
        print('bar')
```

More can be found here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

Answer (score 3):

You want your `search_submissions()` function to be **async** so other functions of your bot can still be invoked and your bot stays responsive. Define it to be `def async` and use `aiohttp` to send async HTTP requests to reddit -- what this does is send off the request, relinquish control to the event loop, and then take back control once the results have been transmitted back. If you use a standard HTTP library here instead then your whole bot will be blocked until the result comes back. This of course only makes sense if the task is mainly I/O-bound and less CPU-bound.

Then call `search_submissions()` in `on_message(message)` -- but call it *asynchronously* using `result = await search_submissions()`. This will resume execution of `on_message` once the result of `search_submissions` is ready.

If you truly want to do something else *in the same context* while waiting on `search_submissions` (which I think is unlikely), dispatch it as `task = asyncio.create_task(search_submissions())`. This will start the task immediately and allow you to do something else within the same function. Once you need the result you will have to `result = await task`.

```
async def search_submissions():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(some_reddit_url) as response:
            return await response.read()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("reddit!hot"):
        result = await search_submissions()
        await message.channel.send(result)
```